# Views Slideshow, items per slide based on screen resolution

Tags: views

I have a [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) slider with 4 items per slide (see below). I am looking for a way to make it change the items per slide number dynamically when the screen width hits a certain breakpoint -for example 3 items per slide when tablet screen and 2 items per slide when mobile screen. Been trying for few days but without success.

Any ideas are welcome.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the option for "Items per slide"? I really dont see this on "Views Slideshow"

Comment: This seems to me to be a valid question. Not sure why it would be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive done it using detect_mobile class and some tweaking of views_slideshow_cycle.theme.inc, changing the $styles['items_per_slide'] variable based on the device detected. Don't see much of an interest so I won't share the code but if someone is interested please let me know. Cheers ;)

Comment: I am facing the same problem. @Ivan: Could you share the code that you have used?